# TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on Int64Index with these indexers [2018-12-01] of type str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am following this tutorial https://github.com/alexhuang1117/personal_projects/blob/master/pm25_analysis/notebooks/.ipynb_checkpoints/01_anomaly_detection_beijing_weather-checkpoint.ipynb

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from datetime import datetime
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler, RobustScaler, robust_scale
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
    
    df = pd.read_csv('../data/processed/beijing.csv', index_col = 0)
    df.head()
    df['2010-01-02':'2010-12-31'].plot(figsize=(20, 12))
```

but when i tried to run this last line i got errors below on my data .. can anyone help

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-14-4972e01b450e> in <module>()
----> 1 df['2018-12-01':'2010-12-15'].plot(figsize=(20, 12))

4 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
_invalid_indexer(self, form, key)    3269         """    3270         raise TypeError(
-> 3271             f"cannot do {form} indexing on {type(self).__name__} with these "    3272             f"indexers [{key}] of type {type(key).__name__}"    3273         )

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on Int64Index with these indexers [2018-12-01] of type str
```

Time column on my data looks like this
[image]

Comment: Where can I download the CSV  from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some quick research, `Int64Index` is a `numpy int64` array. So, make sure that you time column is set as your index and sort it.

```
df = df.set_index('Timestamp').sort_index()
df['2010-01-02':'2010-12-31'].plot(figsize=(20, 12))
```

Here's my research reference https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Int64Index.html

Here's a working example based on your sample data.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for repl,y.. i updated post and added screenshot of my data . i didnt get it could you tell me my changing this code line df['2010-01-02':'2010-12-31'].plot(figsize=(20, 12))

Comment: Hi @Alex you set `Timestamp` as index before plotting your data. I've edited my answers with sample data you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Tried your code on the CSV from the link you posted and it is working fine.
Try upgrading your Pandas - maybe you are working with an older version??

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```